# integrate <?=nl2br($emlak->aciklama);?> php code into $title=" "

Tags: php

I have tried different formats but could not get the right code to function --within the $title quotes. I would like to use the first 80 characters of the page product description to appear in the title of the page (not the page description below the title)

I would like to integrate this php code

```
<?=nl2br($emlak->aciklama);?>
```

within the quotes of below code

```
$title="Detail Turkish Property For Sale in Turkey";
```

I have also tried this example

```
$title="<?=nl2br($emlak->aciklama);?>";
```

### here is the page code i have added to my question

```
<? ob_start();  session_start();

$title="Detail Turkish Property For Sale in Turkey";

include "ust.php";



$sql = "SELECT

            emlakkayit.id,

            emlakkayit.pno,

            emlakkayit.padi,

            emlakkayit.ilce,

            emlakkayit.semt,

            emlakkayit.fiyat,

            emlakkayit.mkare,

            emlakkayit.ksay,

            emlakkayit.bkat,

            emlakkayit.oda,

            emlakkayit.salon,

            emlakkayit.banyo,

            emlakkayit.isitma,

            emlakkayit.aciklama,

            emlakkayit.resim1,

            emlakkayit.resim2,

            emlakkayit.resim3,

            emlakkayit.resim4,

            emlakkayit.resim5,

            emlakkayit.resim6,

            emlakkayit.ozellikler,

            bolge.bolge,

            emlak_turu.tur

        FROM

            emlakkayit 

            LEFT JOIN emlak_turu    ON emlakkayit.eturu=emlak_turu.id 

            LEFT JOIN bolge         ON emlakkayit.ilce=bolge.id 

        WHERE 

            emlakkayit.id='".$_GET[KKId]."'  

        GROUP BY emlakkayit.id 

        ORDER BY emlakkayit.id DESC 

        LIMIT 0,10" ;   

$DB->sorgula($sql);  

$emlak = $DB->objegetir($DB->sorgu_id);

$DB->kapat($DB->sorgu_id);



?>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<tr>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<table width=99% border="0" cellspacing="0">

<tr>

<td width=29% valign="top"><? include "sol.php";?></td>

<td width=71% valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top"><h1 class="header">
  <?=strtoupper($emlak->bolge)?> PROPERTY FOR SALE </h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><a href="detail.php" class="l3">detail</a></P></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?

$sql = "SELECT id FROM emlakkayit WHERE emlakkayit.id<'".$_GET[KKId]."' AND edurum!='3' AND edurum!='2' AND resim1!='' ORDER BY emlakkayit.id DESC LIMIT 0,1" ; 

$DB->sorgula($sql);  

$swp = $DB->objegetir($DB->sorgu_id);

$DB->kapat($DB->sorgu_id);

$onceki = $swp->id ;



$sql = "SELECT id FROM emlakkayit WHERE emlakkayit.id>'".$_GET[KKId]."' AND edurum!='3' AND edurum!='2'  AND resim1!='' ORDER BY emlakkayit.id ASC LIMIT 0,1" ; 

$DB->sorgula($sql);  

$swp = $DB->objegetir($DB->sorgu_id);

$DB->kapat($DB->sorgu_id);

$sonraki = $swp->id ;

unset($swp->id);

?>



<tr>
<td><TABLE WIDTH="520" height="21" BORDER="0" align="center" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" background="images/property_.gif">
  <TR>
    <TD width="11" align="left" class="properties_">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD align="left" class="properties_"><? if($onceki>0) { ?>
        <a href="?KKId=<?=$onceki?>" class="properties">&laquo; PREVIOUS | </a>
        <? }

                else { ?> &laquo; PREVIOUS | <? } 

            ?></TD>
    <TD  align="right" class="properties_"><?   if($sonraki>0) { ?>
        <A HREF="?KKId=<?=$sonraki?>" class="properties">| NEXT &raquo;</A>
        <? }

                else { ?>
  | NEXT &raquo;
  <? } 

              ?>
    </TD>
    <TD width="11"  align="right" class="properties_">&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><span class="normalyazi"><span class="altcizgililinkacik"> #
        <?=$emlak->pno?>
        <img src="resimler/<?=$emlak->resim1?>" alt="Property Detail Turkey" width="197" height="146">    </span></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td><table width=99% border="0">
  <tr>
    <TD height=2></TD>
    <TD width="448" rowspan="2" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" align="left">
        <tr>
          <td width="100%" valign="top" class="normalyazi"><span class="kalinturuncuverdanaCopy"> <span>
            <?=$emlak->bolge?>
            </span> </span><span class="type">-
            <?=$emlak->oda?>
        bedroom </span><span class="property">
        <?=$emlak->tur?>
      </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" class="normalyazi"><span class="price"><span class="property">price:</span> <span class="kalinturuncuverdana"> &euro;
                  <?=number_format($emlak->fiyat);?>
          </span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            <table width="99" border="0" align="left">
              <tr>
                <?

        $ozdizi[1] = "beach1" ;

        $ozdizi[2] = "golf1" ;

        $ozdizi[3] = "inland1" ;

        $ozdizi[4] = "mountain1" ;

        $ozdizi[5] = "town1" ;



        $swp_dizi   = explode(":",$emlak->ozellikler) ;

        $dsayisi = count($swp_dizi);

        for($k=0 ; $k<=$dsayisi;$k++)

        {

            if($swp_dizi[$k]=="1") $ozdizi[1] = "beach" ;   

            if($swp_dizi[$k]=="2") $ozdizi[2] = "golf" ;    

            if($swp_dizi[$k]=="3") $ozdizi[3] = "inland" ;  

            if($swp_dizi[$k]=="4") $ozdizi[4] = "mountain" ;

            if($swp_dizi[$k]=="5") $ozdizi[5] = "town" ;    

        }



        for( $z=1 ; $z<=5 ; $z++ )

        {

            echo "<td><img src=images/".$ozdizi[$z].".gif alt=".$ozdizi[$z]." width=25 height=25 ></td>";

        }

       ?>
              </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="kalinsiyah11Copy">Location:</span> <span class="prop">
            <?=$emlak->semt?>
        -
        <?=$emlak->bolge?>
          </span><span class="kalinsiyah11Copy"> </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="kalinsiyah11Copy">Property Type: </span><span class="prop">
            <?=$emlak->tur?>
          </span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="prop">
            <?=$emlak->oda?>
        Bedroom,
        <?=$emlak->banyo?>
        Bathroom,
        <?=$emlak->salon?>
        Living Room</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="kalinsiyah11Copy">Area: </span> <span class="prop">
            <?=$emlak->mkare?>
        m2</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table></TD>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="210" valign="top"><table width="200" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td><hr size="1" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td class="normalyazi"><table width=99% 



 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" class="normalyazi">

  <tr>

    <td colspan="3" class="normalyazi">

      <form name="form1" method="get" action="enquire.php">

        <table width=29%  border="0">

          <tr>

            <td align="center">

              <div align="left">

                <input name="KKId" type="hidden" id="KKId" value="<?=$emlak->id?>" /> 

                </div></td>

            <td align="right"><div align="left"></div></td>

            </tr>

          <tr>

            <td width="13%"><a href="enquire.php">

              <input name="imageField2" type="image" src="images/property enquire.gif" align="top" width="102" height="29" border="0">
```

```
            <td><div align="left"><img src="images/property form.gif" width="121" height="25" border="0" align="top">

            </div></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

      </form></td>

  </tr>

  <tbody>

    <tr>

      <td height="100" colspan="3" align="left" valign="top" class="AdverDetailFormText"><table width="98%" border="0">

        <tr class="normalyazi">

          <td height="95" valign="top"><h3 align="justify" class="normalyazi">

              <?=nl2br($emlak->aciklama);?></h3></td>

        </tr>

      </table></td>

      </tr>

    <? if($emlak->ksay<>"0"){?>

    <? }if($emlak->bkat<>"0"){?>

    <? }?>

    <tr>

      <td align="left" valign="top" class="AdverDetailFormText">&nbsp;</td>

      <td valign="top" class="AdverDetailFormText">&nbsp;</td>

      <td width="718" valign="top" class="stdFont1">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td width="112" align="left" valign="top" class="AdverDetailFormText"><p class="normalyazi"><strong>Main Features</strong></p></td>

      <td width="12" valign="top" class="AdverDetailFormText"><b>:</b></td>

      <td valign="top" class="stdFont1"><table width=99% border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="normalyazi">

        <tbody>

          <tr>

            <?=checkbox_getir_2($emlak->ozellikler, "emlak_ozellikleri", "ozellik")?>

          </tr>

       </table></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td class="AdverDetailFormText">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="AdverDetailFormText">&nbsp;</td>

      <td class="stdFont1">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><hr size="1" /></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr align="center">
    <td align="left"><? if(trim($emlak->resim1)!=""){ ?>
        <table width="145" border="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td><IMG src="resimler/<?=$emlak->resim1?>" alt="Property For Sale, Turkey" width=145 height=108 border=0 ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="left" bgcolor="#E04215"><div align="center"><span class="clickme"><span>
                <?=$emlak->bolge?>
            </span></span></div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <? }?></td>
    <td align="left"><? if(trim($emlak->resim2)!=""){ ?>
        <table width="145" border="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td><IMG src="resimler/<?=$emlak->resim2?>" alt="Property For Sale, Turkey" width=145 height=108 border=0 ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="left" bgcolor="#E04215">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <?}?>        </td>
    <td align="left"><? if(trim($emlak->resim3)!=""){ ?>
        <table width="145" border="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td><IMG src="resimler/<?=$emlak->resim3?>" alt="Property For Sale, Turkey" width=145 height=108 border=0 ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="left" bgcolor="#E04215">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <?}?>        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td align="left"><? if(trim($emlak->resim4)!=""){ ?>
        <table width="145" border="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td><IMG src="resimler/<?=$emlak->resim4?>" alt="Property For Sale, Turkey" width=145 height=108 border=0 ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="left" bgcolor="#E04215">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <?}?>        </td>
    <td align="left"><? if(trim($emlak->resim5)!=""){ ?>
        <table width="145" border="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td><IMG src="resimler/<?=$emlak->resim5?>" alt="Property For Sale, Turkey" width=145 height=108 border=0 ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="left" bgcolor="#E04215">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <?}?>        </td>
    <td align="left"><? if(trim($emlak->resim6)!=""){ ?>
        <table width="145" border="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td><IMG src="resimler/<?=$emlak->resim6?>" alt="Property For Sale, Turkey" width=145 height=108 border=0 ></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="20" align="left" bgcolor="#E04215">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <?}?>        </td>
  </tr>
</table></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><table width="500" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="justify"><span class="normalyazi">For intermediary sales through our company; we introduce the property owner with the buyer, and help them negotiate the price together. As experts in the region, Turkish Property World, helps you make the right decision.</span></div></td>
  </tr>
</table></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td><form name="form1" method="get" action="enquire.php">

  <table width=29%  border="0">

    <tr>

      <td align="center">

        <div align="left">

          <input name="KKId" type="hidden" id="KKId" value="<?=$emlak->id?>" />

      </div></td>

      <td align="right"><div align="left"></div></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td width="13%"><a href="enquire.php">

        <input name="imageField22" type="image" src="images/property enquire.gif" align="top" width="102" height="29" border="0">

      </td>

      <td><div align="left"><img src="images/property form.gif" width="121" height="25" border="0" align="top"> </div></td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</form></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><TABLE WIDTH="520" height="21" BORDER="0" align="center" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="0" background="images/property_.gif">
  <TR>
    <TD width="11" align="left" class="properties_">&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD align="left" class="properties_"><? if($onceki>0) { ?>
        <a href="?KKId=<?=$onceki?>" class="properties">&laquo; PREVIOUS | </a>
        <? }

                else { ?>
&laquo; PREVIOUS | <? } 

            ?></TD>
    <TD  align="right" class="properties_"><?   if($sonraki>0) { ?>
        <A HREF="?KKId=<?=$sonraki?>" class="properties">| NEXT &raquo;</A>
        <? }

                else { ?>
  | NEXT &raquo;
  <? } 

            ?>
    </TD>
    <TD width="11"  align="right" class="properties_">&nbsp;</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</table></td>

</tr>

</table></td>

</tr>



 <tr>



<td><img src="images/bot_1.jpg" width="761" height="69"></td>



</tr>



<tr>



<td align="center" bgcolor="#D8D5D0"><? include "alt.php";?></td>



</tr>



</table></td>



 <td align="left" valign="top"><? include "sag.php";



 ?></td>



 </tr>



</table>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You would want `$title=nl2br($emlak->aciklama)`..

Comment: i just tried above example the title shows this <title></title> because no quotes. i am stuck with the code, when not between the quotes.

Comment: This makes no sense. you don't show any attempt to use `<title>` tags in your question, how are we supposed to help? Further, `<title>` cannot contain `<br>` tags, so why are you using `nl2br` in the first place? You need to post more context, as it's impossible to help you based on what you've posted so far.

Comment: i have added the page code to my initial question. yes the <title> tags are not in my question. it is when i f5 the page and right click i see <title> tags i tried to read out to you.

Comment: _Far_ too much code. Where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org)? Also this isn't even close to being valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `<?= ?>` here. Just assign the result of the function to the variable:

```
$title = nl2br($emlak->aciklama);
```

Comment: "There is no need for" implies that they are redundant here. They're not. They are erroneous.

Comment: i just tried above example the title shows this <title></title>

Comment: The code you've presented, and my answer, have  *nothing* to do with `<title>` tags. You're going to have to be more specific with what you're trying to do, and show your actual code. Also, if you're trying to output this in the title, what are you doing with `nl2br`? you can't have `<br>` tags in your `<title>`, that function has absolutely no use in building a `<title>` tag.

Comment: as all the page titles are the same for each product, i want the page $title to read the first 80 character from the PRODUCT description --as the page title. 

For example <title>RENEWABLE ENERGY ZONED LAND for sale in Burdur Antalya</title>

here is the source 
    http://www.turkish-property-world.com/detail_land.php?KKId=2276

Comment: i have added the page code to my initial question

Answer (score 1):

`<?= x ?>` means "go into PHP mode, execute `echo x`, then come out of PHP mode again".

But you're already in PHP mode, and you don't want to `echo`, so all of those things can go away: all *you* need is `x`.

So, `$title = nl2br($emlak->aciklama);`

Comment: i just tried above example the title shows this <title></title>

Comment: i have added the page code to my initial question. pls help